# Handling very large images in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, large-files

I can't get Qt to work on images beyond 10,000X10,000. I'm dealing with huge satellite images that are around 2GB each. I considered using memory mapping but the image still occupies  space in memory.

```
QFile file("c://qt//a.ras");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
qint64 size = file.size();
uchar *img=file.map(0,size);
QImage I(img,w,h,QImage::Format_ARGB32);
```

Can anyone tell me a more efficient way to deal with large images in Qt?

Comment: You should tell the reason you can't do it - is it because you run out of memory? Is it a 32-bit-system you are working on?

Comment: What is the problem exactly: runtime crash, out-of-memory error, excessive paging to disk, etc... Lots of ways this can go wrong.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do with the image? Manipulate the bits and stream it out somewhere? Add it to a GUI (perhaps QGraphicsItem?)

Comment: The goal is to only display an Image, no manipulation. There isn't a crash of any sort, but the image isn't displayed if you go beyond 10K X 10K. Might be a Qimage limitation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Qgraphicsview](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsview.html) and a set of image tiles, the view handles all the scrolling and world coords for you.
Then you just have to either pre-chop the images into tiles in advance or pull a section of image data on the fly

Comment: I like this approach. Is there a good example somewhere for this. I went through Qt documentation for Qgraphicsview, but couldn't completly understand how it works. Thanks

Comment: There is a demo of an infinite array of computer chip pictures in Qt

Comment: what is this example called? I have not been able to find it

Comment: @Derek, it doesn't seem to be in the 4.7 demos set, but it's at  http://doc.qt.nokia.com/main-snapshot/demos-chip.html

Comment: @MartinBeckett I'm just wondering how to apply the chips example to this question. In the example they add a bunch of chip graphics items to the scene; if I wanted to apply it to this example, would I add each tile of my image as a graphics item?

Answer (score 5):

Can you use some sort of tiling strategy to load and manipulate the image piecewise, instead of all at once?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using a 32-bit OS and you're running out of address space. The easiest solution may be to use a 64-bit OS (e.g. Windows 7 x64) and compile your app for 64-bit. What is your target platform (Windows, Mac OS X, Linux etc.)?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176048/qt-application-64-bit-windows) may help.

Comment: Nope. This isn't the issue. I still have 500MB on my ram left unused.

Comment: You may have 500 MB left... do you have enough *contiguous* address space? On Windows x86, out of the box you have 2 GB of address space. This isn't two GB of empty space though, DLLs load here and there and heaps are allocated, fragmenting it into smaller blocks. One thing to try is the /3GB switch - this can get you an extra 1 GB of contiguous space for apps (but can cause compatibility issues with some drivers).

Comment: How does one get more continuous memory by changing to 64-bit (dataword size of software) operating system (assuming a 64-bit CPU and constant amount of physical RAM)? Windows uses paging right? Every process has its virtual address space, which pages may be anywhere in physical RAM (but more contiguous?how?)

Comment: @question - With a 32-bit process you have 32-bit pointers - this limits the virtual address space for each process to 4 GB at most (somewhat less on Windows because of fragmentation and the kernel address space). With a 64-bit process you have 64-bit pointers - this limits the theoretical virtual address space to 2^64 (in practice this is limited to 16 TB on Windows x64). Note that neither of these things have anything to do with physical RAM.